# Chapter 10 of Hartl Rails tutorial: Can't get home to render _feed.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been able to jump most hurtles as I move through the Hartl Rails tutorial, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong around 10.4.  I can get everything to render correctly using this **/static_pages/home.html.erb**

```
<% if signed_in? %>
<div class="row">
    <aside class="span4">
        <section>
            <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
        </section>
        <section>
            <%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>
        </section>
    </aside>
    </div>
<% else %>
<div class="center hero-unit">
    <h1>Welcome to The Gentle Introduction Resource</h1>
    <p>
        This is the home page for the
        <a href="http://www.weekendpublisher.com">The Gentle Introduction Resource</a>
        web app.
    </p>

    <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
</div>
<br/>
<%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails"), 'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
```

But then when I include this code:

```
<div class="span8">
        <h3>Micropost Feed</h3>
        <%= render 'shared/feed' %>
    </div>
```

it breaks.

Full **home.html.erb**:

```
<% if signed_in? %>
    <div class="row">
        <aside class="span4">
            <section>
                <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
            </section>
            <section>
                <%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>
            </section>
        </aside>
        <div class="span8">
            <h3>Micropost Feed</h3>
            <%= render 'shared/feed' %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% else %>
    <div class="center hero-unit">
        <h1>Welcome to The Gentle Introduction Resource</h1>
        <p>
            This is the home page for the
            <a href="http://www.weekendpublisher.com">The Gentle Introduction Resource</a>
            web app.
        </p>

        <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails"), 'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
<% end %>

Here is my _feed.html.erb:

    <% If @feed_items.any? %>
    <ol class="microposts">
        <%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @feed_items %>
    </ol>
    <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
    <% end %>
```

And here is my **_feed_item.html.erb**

```
<li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">
<%= link_to gravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %>
<span class="user">
    <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
</span>
<span class="content"><%= feed_item.content %></span>
<span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
</span>
<% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", feed_item, method: delete, 
    data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
    title: feed_item.content %>
<% end %>
</li>
```

Sorry in advance for my markup, this is my first stack overflow question.

Oh and here is the error I'm getting when I attempt to load my local site:

**SyntaxError in Static_pages#home**

Showing /rails_projects/sample_appOct20_2013/app/views/shared/_feed.html.erb where line #7 raised:

/rails_projects/sample_appOct20_2013/app/views/shared/_feed.html.erb:7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end
Extracted source (around line #7):

```
4:  </ol>
5:  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
6: <% end %>
```

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/shared/_feed.html.erb, app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb

Comment: What does your routes.rb file look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its the capital If

should be:

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
<ol class="microposts">
  <%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @feed_items %>
</ol>
<%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

Since this is the case, it thinks that the <% end %> tag is not needed. It really is needed but 'If' (capitalized) is not the same as 'if'(lowercase).

Comment: Give Rubymine a try! It showed me the error in about 2 seconds of copy and pasting your code with a red underline. I use it every day for work.

Comment: Jonathan, thank you SO much, it was that stupid capital If that I was missing over and over again.  I'd say my question is answered, but looks like I have another error popping up.  I'll mess around with that, and post my findings.  Thanks again!

Comment: Okay, so my new error was from adding'<% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", feed_item, method: delete, 
    data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
    title: feed_item.content %>
<% end %>' prematurely.  Once I hid that, everything works great.  It was just that dumb uppercase I that was messing me up!